# How to align elements so CSS fixed doesnt overlap on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to make my navigation menu align itself so it doesn't overlap on page load but overlap when scrolling down (Dynamic nav bar)

What I currently have is here: https://m.omegarealm.tk/
As you can see on the page's initial load the bar overlaps the text, I'd like the nav bar not to overlap the text when the page is loaded but overlap on scroll.

My current CSS is here: https://files.omegarealm.tk/mobile.css

Quick note: The CSS is one line when you access it because cloudflare compresses it. It's indented on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Really? Why downvote? I gave you as much detail as possible. Idiots -.-

Comment: It wasn't me, but you're pasting a link to your site. NOT providing relevant code.

Comment: Pasting a link to it directly is alot easier than copying and copying. My code isnt the most compact of codes.

Comment: It is easier for You. Not to helpers. And, You should add JavaScript code here. Have You done with it something?

Comment: Trying to make my code compact specifically for asking a question on SO has often helped me realize and address the issues I was having. I think if you spend the time in extracting the core issue, it would not be an effort in vain.

Comment: <div style="padding:40px">
<h1>Under construction</h1>
<p>Sorry, please come back later</p>
<br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br>
<br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br>
</div>

Comment: I answered you question below, why was it so difficult to paste your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any JavaScript here. Your "navbar" element seems to be a fixed height so you can achieve what you want simply by setting the top margin of your `body` to be equal to that height, plus a little extra so your content is sitting right on the edge of the fixed element.

```css
body{
    height:5000px;
    margin:52px 10px 10px;
}
#navbar{
    background:red;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar img{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
#navbar p{
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:42px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <img alt="Menu" height="32" src="//files.omegarealm.tk/images/menu_mobile.png" width="32">
    <p>OmegaRealm</p>
</div>
<h1>Under construction</h1>
<p>Sorry, please come back later</p>
```

Comment: Sorry don't worry, cloudflare's cache needed purging. It's fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is fixed is has no relevance to the content below it. Wrap the body content and apply a margin to the top:

```js
var navHeight = $('#navbar').height() + 30;
$('section').css('marginTop', navHeight);
```

```css
#navbar {

  background-color: red;

  left: 0;

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <img width="32px" height="32px" align="left" style="padding: 5px;" src="//files.omegarealm.tk/images/menu_mobile.png">
  <font size="5">
<b>
OmegaRealm
</b>
</font>
</div>

<section style="height: 2000px">
  <h1>Under construction</h1>
  <p>Sorry, please come back later</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Approving of your answer, it's more relevant than the one below.

Comment: if you could mark mine as the correct answer then please.

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to allow me. Done now

Comment: Working great, thanks alot!
You can see the result here if you like: https://m.omegarealm.tk/